# Default index in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, clustered-index, non-clustered-index

When I use the below query to create index for a column in MS SQL Server

```
create index IX_indexname on tablename(columnname);
```

without mentioning it as clustered or non clustered index, what index will be created? Which is the default index?

Comment: [tag:sql] refers to the SQL Standard. Are you working with a *specific* RDBMS? If so,please [edit] and add a tag for your product. Then, consider that there's probably *documentation* for the product that will spell this out when you read about `create index` in there.

Comment: Which DBMS are you talking about?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Default would be non clustered.

You can refer to documentation when in doubt..

Below is the syntax from [MSDN for create index statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx)

> CREATE [ UNIQUE ] [ CLUSTERED | NONCLUSTERED ] INDEX index_name

everything in Square brackets is optional,so you would be left with

> create index index_name

MSDN again says

> If CLUSTERED is not specified, a nonclustered index is created.

Answer (score 2):

As you're referring to clustered indexes, I'm guessing this question refers to MS SQL Server.
Unless you explicitly specify it to be clustered, an index would be non-clustered.